# Сборка и запуск кода из исходников на Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, компиляция

Есть код на С++, к примеру:

```
#include <iostream> // source.cpp

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n; 
    cout << n;
}
```

Так же к нему есть несколько текстовых файлов, содержимое которых подаётся на вход программы.

Можно ли на Python написать скрипт, который принимал бы на вход название файла, отдавала команду компиляции (в моём случае `g++ -o source path/to/filename.cpp`), а позже запускал программу на С++ внутри себя и подавал ей значения из текстовых файлов на вход и сохранял все выходные данные программы? Подскажите как это можно реализовать. Или может уже есть похожие решения (не обязательно на Python).

Comment: да на чем угодно можно сделать, это же всего две консольные команды - собрать и выполнить.

Comment: @user7860670 а как быть с тем, что программе надо подавать файлы на вход и собирать всё, что она выводит?

Comment: вам стоит почитать про перенаправление стандартного ввода / вывода в консоли